# Python beautiful soup/ Find

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My Question is that when i print the links list out it prints a handsome list in the terminal but i don't know why the links(list) does not contain the find method? 
Moreover this same code was working on my teachers's ide

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

param = {'s': 'zombie'}
r = requests.get('http://chilltime.pk/search', params=param

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find('tbody')
links = soup.findAll('td')

for i in links:
    item_text = i.find('a').text
    item_href = i.find('a').attrs['href']

    if item_text and item_href:
        print(item_text)
        print(item_href)
```

```
ERROR:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/AFFAN ULHAQ/PycharmProjects/Beautiful/bsp.py", line 19, in <module>
item_text = i.find('a').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**
```

Comment: many a tags do not contain any texts

Comment: @Affan Haq, website is down now https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/chilltime.pk.html . It's most likely that the code doesn't find any A tags in at least one of the TD tags, thus it can't return the text of a NoneType

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

params = {
    's': 'zombie'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.findAll("a", href=True)
    for tar in target:
        print(tar.text, tar['href'])


main("http://chilltime.pk/search")
```

Comment: It seems that he's looking for links inside of TDs not the entire page

Comment: @ThaerA Oh, noticed it now. BTW the site itself is currently down.

Answer (score 1):

It most likely the "i" variable iterating links does not have the attribute "a", that is, there isn't a link inside your html cell. Maybe it's you can check if you really have a link

```
for i in links:
    item_text = i.find('a').text if i.find('a') else False
    item_href = i.find('a').attrs['href'] if i.find('a') else False
```